# How to view logs in uboot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, serial-port

I have a linux device running U-Boot and booting Ubuntu Core 18 that is having problems with its serial interface and networking. Because of these problems, I can't configure it via ssh or minicom. I can, however, establish a serial connection via minicom while in the bootloader. I can see logs, but I can't figure out a way to access them.

```
# ls mmc 0:2 system-data/var/log
<DIR>       4096 .
<DIR>       4096 ..
           28032 wtmp
               0 btmp
               0 lastlog
```

Is there a way to show these log files from the U-Boot interface?

Comment: Which the model and version of device mentioned on the question?

Comment: This is a custom device running an ARM processor.

Comment: *"I can, however, serial into the bootloader."* -- *"Serial"* is not a verb.  *"Is there a way to show these log files from the uboot interface?"* -- It's spelled U-Boot.  Command capabilities depend on what was configured into the build you are using.  Use the `help` command to check if any `ext2` or `ext4` commands are available.  It probably won't matter though.  Linux log files in the **/var** directory are accessible from a **tmpfs** only while Linux is active.

Comment: *"Is there a way to show these log files from the uboot interface?"* --  Assuming that such files are actually accessible from the SD card or e.MMC device, the standard set of U-Boot commands would require a two-step procedure: (1) load the file contents into memory  (e.g. the `ext4load` command), and then (2) dump/display memory (e.g. the `md` command).  But your post shows a combination of shell (i.e. `ls`) and U-Boot command syntax?